# MS Access Report won't open in Office 365 C2R - Error 3761 'the decimal field's precision is too small'

Tags: sql, ms-access, office365, ms-access-reports

I have a report that works on all of our office computers except two that use office 365.  The majority of users have windows 10 pc's with access 2013 runtime, and the report runs without issue on these.  Access is our front end to a SQL express db.  On the two PC's with office 365, the report won't open, they just get:

> Error 3761: the decimal field's precision is too small to accept the numeric you attempted to add.

There are 2 numeric fields on the report; `Sum(ActivityValue)`, and `%Complete`.  These are calculated fields based on these query columns:

```sql
ProdActivityLength: DLookUp("SumofLength","qryProdActivitybyDept","itemserialno = " & [dbo_Production_Items].[ItemSerialNo])
```

```sql
ActivityValue: ([ProductionValue]/[ProdActivityLength])*[Length]
```

```sql
%complete: 1-((DSum("length","qryProdSchedCompletion","itemserialno = " & [ItemSerialNo])/[ProdActivityLength]))
```

The SQL fields `Length` and `ProductionValue` are decimal 18,2

`Sum(ActivityValue)` on the report is `Currency`, with 0 decimal places. 
`%Complete` is Percentage with Auto decimal places.

I cannot think why the percentage field would be causing an issue, so I've been concentrating on the decimal fields.

The report is not trying to write the data back to anywhere, so I've tried changing the 0 decimal places to auto and to 2, but still get the error.

I have also tried changing the controlsource to `int(sum(activityvalue)` but the same error still occurs.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this error in Office 365, or other ideas for how to resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: @Rene, backend is SQLServer Express so I would think there are no table calculated fields. I expect these calculations are in query. Your first link fails and not sure how second is relevant.

Comment: Suggest you eliminate each of the calculations one at a time and see if one is source of issue. If `%Complete` is a field name, advise not to use punctuation/special characters in names for anything. Edit question to show sample data.

Comment: Thanks June, I will try that and will add sample data later when i’m in the office.

Comment: @June7 - sorry for the delay in progress with this, other work took priority over Christmas. I did as you suggested and eliminated one calculation at a time. I found the cause was the ActivityValue calculation, and I have resolved the error by amending the query to calculate it as Int(([ProductionValue]/[ProdActivityLength])*[Length]). Forcing the integer at the record source rather than in the report has removed the error.